# What is $f(x)$ for which $f(x)+3 f(1-x)=2x^2+x-7$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have tried to get algebraic formula of $f(x)$ such that :$f(x)+3 f(1-x)=2x^2+x-7$, I have used the assumption that $f(1)=f(0)=0$ But it dosn't work because $x=0$ is not a solution , Now if we try to solve :$ 2x^2+x-7=0$ then we have $f(1-x)=-\frac13 f(x)$ , But how I can get $f(x)$ from the latter equality ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace $x$ by $1-x$. This gives the equation
$$
f(1-x) + 3f(x) = 2(1-x)^2 + (1-x) -7.
$$
Now you have two equations in two unknowns $f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$, which you can then solve for $f(x)$. To solve, you could write $a:=f(x)$ and $b:=f(1-x)$, use the first equation to express $b$ in terms of $a$, then plug this formula for $b$ into the second equation, and arrive at a formula for $a$ alone.

Comment: Pleas try to exaplain more in detaill

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Where there is an $x$ in the equation, replace it with $1-x$.

Comment: I think the solution is : x^2/2 - 2x -5/8

Comment: @zeraouliarafik That is correct.